# Azure Data Flow Getting Error on Update and Insert

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

When i am joining Two tables and allowing Alter Update and Insert getting this Error

**Allowing delete, insert, or update requires an Alter Row transformation to set row policies.**

[image: Screenshot]

Then i created the Alter Rows Now i am getting this Error When i am running trigger

> {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate,
>   ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression 'Order
>   ID'","target":"pipeline/SaleDB/runid/1cf1e695-dff8-4330-8401-b4ebb86d573f","details":null}}

Answer (score 1):

Error regarding 'Order ID', this column is a duplicate mostly coming from the Distinct (Aggregate) and Select1 (duplicate stream for OriginalData). So you can put a select before sink drop the duplicate column. That will solve this problem.

Regarding AlterRow. Only alter row is the transformation which can mark rows to update, delete, upserts. In case you intention is to update some rows, then you need Alter Row, in case intention is not to update then you can remove Allow Update from sink.